# Hibernate loading one by one not needed entities marked as lazy fetch type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Using postgresql database through hibernate. 
I have an entity(table) TeamInfo (bb_team_info) and trying to execute the following code:

```
strQuery.append("SELECT * from bb_team_info WHERE id in (SELECT bb_team_info_id FROM bb_team_league_info tl WHERE tl.bb_league_id = :leagueID)");
    Query query2 = em.createNativeQuery(strQuery.toString(), TeamInfo.class);
    query2.setParameter("leagueID", leagueID.getId());
    List<TeamInfo> myteaminfolist = query2.getResultList();
```

Here is the TeamInfo class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bb_team_info")
@BatchSize(size=50)
public class TeamInfo implements Serializable {
private Integer id;
... some fields here ...
private TeamFinance finance;
private Manager manager;

public TeamInfo() {
}

....

@OneToOne (mappedBy="teamInfo", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Manager getManager() {
    return manager;
}
...


@OneToOne(targetEntity=TeamFinance.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="teamInfo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public TeamFinance getFinance() {
    return finance;
}

}
```

Actual requests that are made (seen from postgresql logs):

```
SELECT * from bb_team_info WHERE id in (SELECT bb_team_info_id FROM bb_team_league_info tl WHERE tl.bb_league_id = $1)
```

Which is what exactly was expected but then I see many queries like this:

```
select ... from bb_team_finances teamfinanc0_ where teamfinanc0_.bb_team_info_id=$1...
select ... from bb_manager where manager0_.bb_team_info_id=$1...
select ... from bb_team_finances teamfinanc0_ where teamfinanc0_.bb_team_info_id=$1...
select ... from bb_manager where manager0_.bb_team_info_id=$1...
```

Why is hibernate selecting those tables if fetch type set to lazy? And why it wouldn't do it at least in two queries (select all managers first then finances)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate must fetch OneToOne relations of an entity eagerly, if the entity does not "own" them. This is because it needs to know whether to use `null` for the relation or a proxy/entity.

For doing the loading in two queries, you need a different fetch strategy. Use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`. Here are some nice examples: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/

Comment: is there any way to tell hibernate that it should use proxy as the relation always exists in the database?

Comment: What if I do the bidirectional relations?

Comment: Try setting `optional = false` on the `@OneToOne`